# Transferring data using java socket

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have developed a very simple Client and a Server softwares using Java socket. The client generates a "Draw object" and I'm able to send it to the server correctly trough a socket (I'm using Gson to convert it to a String, since my client will be an Android device and RMI is not available natively).

The point is that I need to send many "Draw objects" to my server (one object per second, for N minutes).

My code currently does this:

1. Open socket connection
2. Capture the Draw Object
3. Send object to Server
4. Close socket connection

On the server side a have a Thread that loops (inside the run method) that receives the data and manipulates it.

My question is: Is there a way to send them (continuously) without need to close the client socket connection or is this the correct pattern?

To be more specific. Is there a way to have the following instructions?

1. Open socket connection
2. Loop

   2.1. Capture draw object & send it to server
3. When draws are over, close connection

Comment: Yea, you can do that.  Give it a try writing the code yourself.

Comment: Thanks @StephenC. I have already written the code, but it only gets the first object and simply ignores the rest. The solution I've found was to close & re-open the socket connection to transmit each object. It is working btw, I was just wondering if it was the right solution. Thanks again.

Comment: No that was not the correct solution to your problem.  And not the correct *approach* either.

Comment: Thanks again @StephenC. Could you just give some hints? I do not want any code, just some ideas on how to approach this problem.

Comment: Does the solution include to encapsulate messages and to delimit them by an application-level protocol? The point here is that I cannot rely on BufferedReader.readLine(), right?